# How to implement two-way binding with additional checks

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

There is a `UISwitch` and a `ControlProperty<Bool>` which are bound each other. However I cannot use standard two-way binding operator `<->` because of the following requirements:

If user turns `UISwitch` ON, I need to check some condition and, if not met, show an alert and revert `UISwitch` back to OFF state. `ControlProperty` must remain intact.
If condition met, `ControlProperty` becomes `true`.

If user turns `UISwitch` OFF, `ControlProperty` becomes `false`.

If `ControlProperty` has been (externally) changed, `UISwitch` must reflect its state unconditionally (as normal binding works). The condition must not be checked.

I tried the following (maybe naive) approach:

```
property.bind(to: cell.switch.rx.isOn).disposed(by: cell.disposeBag)

cell.switch.rx.isOn.bind { [unowned self] isOn in
    if !isOn || viewModel.allowTurnEmailNotificationOn {
        property.onNext(isOn)
    } else {
        let alert = MyAlertViewController()
        present(alert, animated: true) { [weak cell] in
            // revert switch back to OFF state
            cell?.switch.isOn = false
        }
    }
}.disposed(by: cell.disposeBag)
```

Generally, it works, but there is a bug: when `ControlProperty` changes to TRUE due to some external event, it sets `UISwitch` ON, which in turn launches checking `if !isOn || viewModel.allowTurnEmailNotificationOn`. As a result, the alert appears.
I only want to perform this check if user manually turns `UISwitch` ON.

Comment: Something else is going on that you haven't told us about. The `switch.rx.isOn` observable will not emit a value unless the *user* manipulates it. Programatic changes will not cause `isOn` to emit. Maybe it has something to do with the way you created the ControlProperty?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `Driver` instead of `bind`, and observe the `onNext` event:

```
        let switchDriver = cell.switch.rx.isOn.asDriver()
        let aFlag = !isOn || viewModel.allowTurnEmailNotificationOn
        
        switchDriver
            .filter { aFlag }
            .drive(onNext: { isOn in
                property.onNext(isOn)
            })
            .disposed(by: cell.disposeBag)

        switchDriver
            .filter { !aFlag }
            .drive(onNext: { isOn in
                let alert = MyAlertViewController()
                present(alert, animated: true) { [weak cell] in
                    cell?.switch.setOn(false, animated: false)
                }
            })
            .disposed(by: cell.disposeBag)
```

2. If you see the same issue then ignore the first event (by using `.skip(1)`). First event might be triggering due to observable setup.